# How to negate \rhd

Tags: symbols

Is there a good way to represent the negation of `\rhd`?. I have tried something like `\not\rhd`, but it does not look nice. Looking around I haven't found any good suggestion.

Comment: `\ntriangleright`?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `\rhd` as a relation symbol, because it's a *binary* operation symbol. You can find it in `latexsym` (deprecated) or `amsfonts`:

```
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\lhd}     {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"43}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\unlhd}   {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"45}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\rhd}     {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"42}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\unrhd}   {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"44}
```

The same symbols used as relation symbols are called differently:

```
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\vartriangleright} {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"42}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\vartriangleleft}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"43}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\trianglerighteq}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"44}
\ams@DeclareMathSymbol{\trianglelefteq}   {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"45}
```

and `amssymb` (that loads `amsfonts`) has

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ntrianglerighteq}{\mathrel}{AMSb}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ntrianglelefteq}{\mathrel}{AMSb}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ntriangleleft}  {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ntriangleright} {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"37}
```

So the answer is to load `amssymb` and to use `\ntriangleright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$x\ntriangleright y$

\end{document}
```

[image]